# Is this a case for $\gcd$ of rational numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

The below exercise appears in a book in section of GCD, and linear Diophantine equation (LDE).

> A square of side $1$ is divided in $a$ strips by equally spaced $(a-1)$ red lines parallel to a side, and is divided in $b$ strips by equally spaced $(b-1)$ blue lines parallel to red strips. What is the minimum distance between the red and blue lines.

For application of GCD, need form linear Diophantine equations(LDEs) to use the properties, assume WLOG (hoping that this would not affect the solution in other cases), that $a \nmid b, b\nmid a$.
So, $(a,b)=1$ and this should help to form the LDE $ax + by =1$.

> To get the minimum distance, may be the book's answer helps: it is given as $(a,b)/ab.$

I want to at least see the logic of this answer, if there is division of a side of unit length into $5$ and $6$ parts by $4$ red and $5$ blue lines respectively, then how come the minimum distance is $1/30$. 
If I draw on a graph paper, then the lines are as shown below :

$$
\begin{align}
0.2 <--> & \ 0.166 \\
0.4 <--> & \ 0.332 \\
0.6 <--> & \ 0.498 \\
0.8 <--> & \ 0.664 \\
none <--> & \ 0.830 \\
\end{align}
$$

The minimum distance is between $0.830, 0.8 => 0.030 = 1/30.$ 
So, the author wants to take the linear combination (in my example) of $-a'.4 + b'.5$ to arrive at the minimum value of $1/30$, where $a'$ is for red strip length ($=0.2 = 1/a $), and $b'$ is for blue. Note that $a$ = #red strips =  #red lines +1, $b$ =#blue strips= #blue lines +1, even though the distance is between lines only.

So, effectively the question reduces to finding the Bezout's coefficients for the smallest possible linear combination, which for my example is :$a=0.2, b = 0.166$. So, is $(a,b) = 1/(5.6)$ an example of $\gcd$ for rational numbers.

Comment: I've been trying to make sense of the question, and have not yet succeeded. You use the term "strips" at first to mean the regions between the red lines and between the blue lines. There is no mention of color for the strips themselves, and obviously each set of strips contains almost all the points in the square. But then the question asks about the minimum distance between the "red strips" and "blue strips", that quite evidently overlap, so that distance would be $0$. Apparently we are now using "strips" to mean the lines, not the regions between?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes you are correct, I am sorry for the confusion. Will edit soon.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I hope an answer or reference or hint even will be enough.

Comment: I wish that for lower score persons, the bounty amount be lesser, say 5 not 50.

Comment: The first thing I noticed is that $\frac 13 \neq 0.333$  This is math, not engineering, and equals *means* equals.  If you are working with fractions you should work with fractions because they are exact.  Then I noticed there is not a question here.  What are you asking?

Comment: @RossMillikan It is very much a question, I have just tried to draw some sort of logic from the crisp answer. I hope to derive the highlighted part, as being equal to the stated answer of $(a,b)/ ab$. Regarding my approximation, I am sorry but wanted some sort of reasoning, and it was for drawing on graph paper, so I hope some approximation would have been there.

Comment: @RossMillikan Please respond as to if any doubts are there.

Comment: I think my answer is that there is no GCD in the rationals because they are a field so every number divides every other.  You can express two rationals in lowest terms and ask about the GCD of the numbers in those two expressions.  That is productive in some cases.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: It means something in that direction, but the derivation of the answer (minimum distance =$(a,b)/(a.b)$) is needed. Your answer states : $(a/b ,c/d) => ..., \exists a,b,c,d \in \mathbb {Z}.$ I am not clear about how to fill in the blanks, taking analogy from integers - where found the highest common factor - should find all factors and then the common factors. Considering two not co-primes: let $4,6$, have for $\frac{1}{4} , \frac{1}{6}$, the need to first find common factors. That all I can say about with confidence.

Comment: @RossMillikan If you could please vet my comments about your statement: "rationals are a field, so every number divides the other, so no GCD is possible." My statement : 'there is no primes in rationals'. Also, is better to say : "rationals are a field", or to say: "rationals are closed under division".

Comment: All of these are pointing at the same thing.  In a ring like the integers you can add, subtract, multiply and sometimes divide.  In a field you can always divide (except by $0$).  You lose the concept of primes because every element is a unit.  When you say rationals are closed under division that says you can always divide (and you need to exclude zero).  I haven't thought about the subtleties that may lurk in the distinctions of wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really asking about $\min \left(\frac k{a-1}, \frac m{b-1}\right)$ where $k,m$ are naturals and $k \lt a-1, m \lt b-1$.  It will be $\frac 1{\operatorname{lcm}(a-1,b-1)}=\frac {\gcd(a-1,b-1)}{(a-1)(b-1)}$ and your approach is the right way to find them.

Comment: But, one hitch: $k,m$ are not factored in your formula, only the denominators are. It seems logical that the entire proper fraction is factored in.

Comment: Hopefully, I was clear in my last comment.

Comment: No, they are not.  They are just the stripe numbers.  The point is that you will be able to find one pair of stripes that are as close as possible using Bezout

Comment: I had assumed strips with $(a,b)=1$, but your answer consider lines. This has no connection/complication with the ratio in your answer, but otherwise it cannot be guaranteed that $(a-1), (b-1)$ will also be primes.             Apart from this there are few more issues: (i) Your last comment if could be supplemented with some example, say for my problem of $a=5, b=6, k =1, m =1.$ (ii) Also, the ratio is: $(4,5)/20 = 1/20.$ This is different from $1/30.$ (iii) How can the ratio of $1/20$ assist in finding one pair of strips.

Comment: Your question asks about the distance between lines, not between the strips.  The strips will overlap, so it only makes sense to talk about the distance between the lines.  The use of $a-1,b-1$ comes because the spacing of the lines is $\frac 1{a-1}, \frac 1{b-1}$.  We don't care if $a-1$ and $b-1$ are prime or not.  In your example with $a=5, a-1=4$ is not prime.  We only care if $a-1$ and $b-1$ are coprime.  If so, there will be a place they are within $\frac 1{(a-1)(b-1)}$.  The general statement is the minimum spacing will be $\frac {\gcd(a-1,b-1)}{(a-1)(b-1)}$

Comment: To find the pair of lines with minimum spacing, you use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).